# sorting, splitting, checking array with nested loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

iam new in progamming, how to do

```
$array={a,b,c,d,e,f}

if $x={a,b,c} -> $y={d,e,f}
if $x={d,e,f} -> $y={a,b,c}
if $x={d,f,a} -> $y={b,c,e}
```

how to make $y like that with nested loop or check it one by one ?
thankyou expert!

Comment: using [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: You do know that this is not PHP syntax right ?

Comment: You haven't even tried to search how to create arrays in php, have you?

Comment: nooo, its just an example :0, thankyou btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for nested solution, then try this:

```
<?php

$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

function get_what_is_left ($input){

    $count = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
        $exist = false;
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($input); $j++){
            if($array[$i] == $input[$j]){
                $exist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$exist){
            $y[$count] = $array[$i];
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $y;
}


/** You can change the array content as you wish **/
$x = array('a','b','c'); 

/** You get the result by calling the function **/
$y = get_what_is_left($x);
```

`array_diff()` will be the simplest solution to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard PHP function [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), you can do:

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

$x = ['a','b','c'];
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
var_dump($x, $y);

$x = ['d','e','f'];
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
var_dump($x, $y);

$x = ['d','f','a'];
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
var_dump($x, $y);
```

and you don't need any kind of looping or sorting

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MWE9m)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array= array(a, b, c, d, e, f);

$x = array(a, b, c);
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($y);  // Shows (d, e, f)
```

---

```
$x = array(d, e, f);
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($y);  // Shows (a, b, c)
```

---

```
$x = array(d, f, a);
$y = array_diff($array, $x);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($y);  // Shows (b, c, e)
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD